# Unable to boot windows 8 after formatting ubuntu partition and reinstalled ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue, boot-repair

I had ubuntu 12.04 lts, and windows 8, dual boot was working fine..but i had lots of problem with my ubuntu, so one day, out of frustration , i formatted ubuntu drive from my windows,
now, i am not able to boot windows, grub rescue opens up.
So, to fix that, i installed ubuntu again on the same hard drive partition as before using a live usb thinking that boot repair would solve it for me.
but, after installing boot-repair, i get a message "EFI Detected, please check options"

now, clicking recommended repair, i get an error message..
EFI detected. Please use Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd) which contains an EFI-compatible version of this software.

I am stuck now, what to do with this iso file that i downloaded, moreover what to do overall to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO file you have can be either **burnt on a CD or on a live-USB**.  (the same way you downloaded the Ubuntu ISO to create your Ubuntu disk).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i think i couldn't quite get you. What to do after burning the iso file. and yes more importantly, is my problem clear to you or should i explain again?

Comment: After burning the ISO file, insert the disk, reboot your computer, the Boot-Repair menu will appear. Choose `Recommended Repair`.  If any issue, indicate the URL that will appear.